# hex() function returns wrong values - why?

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.net project in that I need to convert a character into an hex value. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/963zt96e(v=vs.90).aspx, I tried this (example):

```
Dim sChar as String = "€"
Dim sNum as Integer = AscW(sChar)
Dim sHex as String = hex(sNum).ToString
```

When I set a breakpoint after that, I get these values in direct console:

```
?sNum
8364
?hex(sNum)
"20AC"
```

Which is correct and works as expected.

But the value calculated in running program is garbage:

```
?sHex
"20254"
```

Why do I get different results in running code and direct input console?
And how do I get the expected string value (`"20AC"`)?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: What is the value of sNum? Maybe it's an encoding problem.

Comment: Why is `hex` lowercase? Do you have some other function that you called `hex`?

Comment: `hex` ist just lowercase because I typed it instead of copying it. I have no function that manually calculates hex values as I expect a powerful framework like .NET to have such a trivial function built-in. I was just wondering about twice the same = two different results.

Answer (score 0):

okay, found a solution (but no explaination)

`sHex = convert.ToString(sNum, 16)`

I cannot explain these wrong values, but the code above works for me, just in case that someone else has the same problem.